# Schematic Feedback

Tags: microcontroller, relay, contact

I am looking for design feedback regarding the following schematic. 
The idea is very simple. 
The Controller board pulls the relay coil terminal low on the relay board to activate the relay.The relay board is 6 feet away from the controller board.

Once the relay is activated the brushless pump turns on. 
The 220uf caps on the 12v line is used to keep the voltage high enough momentarily to have the microcontroller save a value in EEPRom before shutting down.
Looking to hear your comments/feedback. 
The relay contact  generates a bit of contact noise upon closure. Attached is the scope shot taken across the relay Common contact as it forms contact with the pump 12v line.

Will the contact noise interfere with the microcontroller function at some point?
Thank you

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work ok.

one possible improvement would to separate the 330uF used before the 5V regulator from the 12V supply using a diode, this stops the the pump sdtart-up current from draining the capacitor, and reduces wear on the relay contacts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5HZkp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @jansen Good idea, currently I have C1 before diode D1 shown on your schematic. Should I do anything about the relay contact bounce? do you think that relay bounce is harmful and should be fixed or be left as is?

Comment: you could fit an RC snubber across the contacts, say 100nF and 10 ohms, but I'm really familiar with that domain